# Shulchan Aruch - Advice?

Tags: halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

I have heard quoted in the name of a gadol that the first 8 simanim of SA are advice ( הנהגות טובות) as opposed to actual halacha. I am looking for some sort of source either backing this or debunking it.

Comment: no i mean the first 8 simanim about how get dressed, use the bathroom and other hanhagos haboker

Comment: Well the Beur Halacha brings from the Semak that tsnius is a mitzvah doraisa, so how could those simmanim be advice?

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein holds that a lot of the bathroom protocol described there applied when people didn't have toilet paper or running water; the particular actions constituting "appropriate behavior" may depend on the culture and technology.

Comment: @Shalom would that mean it would therefore be advice and not "halacha"?

Comment: I don't think that can be true.